# Is there a way to play all actions that are part of one armature one after another?

Tags: animation, actions

So I have a few actions I made for my FPS hands that I would like to play one after another and render it as a video, but I cant seem to find where or how to do that. Is that even possible?

Comment: you need to push down each action into the NLA (Nonlinear Animation window) and move the strips that it will create

Comment: Do you mind showing me how? Im unfamiliar with NLA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to push down each action that you want to show from the *Dope Sheet* into the *NLA* (*Nonlinear Animation window*):

[image]

Then open the *NLA* and move each strip (you can also put them all on the same track). Press <kbd>G</kbd> to move a strip, right click on a track to move it up or down:

[image]

If you press <kbd>N</kbd> in the *NLA* you'll have access to the *NLA* properties, for example you can decide the effect of the selected strip, *Extrapolation > Hold* means that the strip below the one selected won't be able to act. If you want them to act, choose *Nothing*, or put the strips above this one:

[image]

If you want the *NLA* to play you need to close the action playing in the *Dope Sheet*, action playing in the *Dope Sheet* will play primarily.

To quickly edit an action, select its strip in the *NLA* and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the strip will turn green, the action will automatically appear in the *Dope Sheet*.

Comment: Oh i see, and how do i play them back? It only plays one that i have selected in the action editor.

Comment: If you want the NLA to play you need to close the action playing in the Dope Sheet, action playing in the Dope Sheet will play primarily

Comment: If you put them all in one track, you can also just click the star button to play it.

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you so much man.

Comment: @moonboots By closing the action in the Dope Sheet, do you mean mousing over the strip in the NLA and press Tab, or how exactly do you close an action in the Dope Sheet?

Comment: click on the X button on the right of the action name